# Select the highest row based on MySQL SUM result, with relations

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, inner-join, max

I have the following `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT
s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname, s.isActive, 
    c.city_name,
    sd.student_startdate, sd.student_enddate,
    SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total
        FROM students s 
            INNER JOIN cityselections c ON c.city_id = s.student_city_id
            INNER JOIN studentdates sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id
            LEFT JOIN studentcourseplan scp ON scp.student_id = s.student_id
            LEFT JOIN studentcourseplanelements scpe ON scpe.scpe_cpl_id = scp.cpl_id
                GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
```

This can output:

```
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
| student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname | isActive | city_name  | student_startdate | student_enddate | total |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
| 83         | John              | Doe              | 1        | Dallas     | 2012-07-23        | 2012-09-30      | 413   |
| 84         | Derp              | Derpson          | 1        | Texas      | 2012-07-01        | 2012-08-26      | 413   |
| 85         | Barack            | Obama            | 1        | Washington | 2012-08-02        | 2012-08-31      | 2     |
| 85         | Barack            | Obama            | 1        | Washington | 2012-08-02        | 2012-08-31      | 153   |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------+------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Now I would only like to print the row with the highest value in column `total` for each `student_id`

I tried `MySQL` `MAX()` but I couldn't make it work.

How should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query...

```
SELECT A.student_id, A.student_firstname, A.student_lastname, A.isActive, 
    A.city_name,
    A.student_startdate, A.student_enddate,
    MAX(A.total)
 FROM (SELECT
s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname, s.isActive, 
    c.city_name,
    sd.student_startdate, sd.student_enddate,
    SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total
        FROM students s 
            INNER JOIN cityselections c ON c.city_id = s.student_city_id
            INNER JOIN studentdates sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id
            LEFT JOIN studentcourseplan scp ON scp.student_id = s.student_id
            LEFT JOIN studentcourseplanelements scpe ON scpe.scpe_cpl_id = scp.cpl_id
                GROUP BY scp.cpl_id) AS A
GROUP BY A.student_id;
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: You're query may work but is incorrect. You should not be including attributes in the select list which are not contained in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a subquery.

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname, s.isActive,
  c.city_name, sd.student_startdate, sd.student_enddate,
    (SELECT SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) 
       FROM studentcourseplan scp
       LEFT JOIN studentcourseplanelements scpe ON scpe.scpe_cpl_id = scp.cpl_id
       WHERE scp.student_id = s.student_id) AS scpe_estemated_days
FROM students s
INNER JOIN cityselections c ON c.city_id = s.student_city_id
INNER JOIN studentdates sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bd8c/1).

I would advise against using shubhansh's answer as it selecting attributes which are not contained in the aggregate, which is poor practice.

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL
>   because the name column in the select list does not appear in the
>   GROUP BY:
>
> ```
> SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
>   FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
>   WHERE o.custid = c.custid
>   GROUP BY o.custid;
> ```
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL.

See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).